# Select specific attribute from SDE.ST_Geometry UDT? (without using accessor functions)

Tags: geometry, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

*Oracle 18c; ArcGIS 10.7.1*

---

I have an SDE.ST_Geometry polyline feature class.

As an experiment/learning exercise, I am trying to learn how to interact directly with the user-defined type (UDT) SHAPE column.

I can select the SHAPE column in an SQL client which returns a collection of attributes from the UDT:

```
select 
    shape 
from 
    a_test_fc

SHAPE                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ST_GEOMETRY(4,37,671828.7852,4861707.1775,671839.2487,4861717.6411,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,32.9250330071201,26917,(BLOB))                                         

1 rows selected.
```

---

And I can see that the [docs](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm) describe the UDT attributes as follows:

> The attributes of the spatial type represent the following
> information:
>
> - Entity: The type of geometric feature stored in the spatial column (linestring, multilinestring, multipoint, multipolygon, point, or
>   polygon), the value of which is a bit mask derived from the
>   st_geom_util stored procedure.
> - Numpts: The number of points defining the geometry; for multipart geometries, this includes the separators between each part, one point
>   for each separator.
> - Minx, miny, maxx, maxy: The spatial envelope of the geometry
> - Area: The area of the geometry
> - Len: The perimeter length of the geometry
> - SRID: Contains the identifier for the geometry that links it to its associated spatial reference (coordinate system) record in the
>   ST_Spatial_References table
> - Points: Contains the byte stream of the point coordinates that define the geometry

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to select **specific attributes** from the ST_Geomtery UDT?

I'm aware that there are *"accessor functions that take a single ST_Geometry as input and return the requested property value as a number."* So there isn't a practical need to directly select individual attributes from the UDT — I could just use those accessor functions if required. I'd just like to determine if it's possible to interact directly with the UDT attributes as a way to learn more about spatial database development.

*I tried researching non-GIS UDTs, and how to select their attributes (example: I tried selecting SHAPE.POINTS). But that just resulted in an error: `ORA-00904: "SHAPE"."POINTS": invalid identifier`. And yes, I'm aware that the POINTS attribute is stored as a byte stream and won't be useful in any practical sense.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, all we need to do is use a table alias (I've used an alias of "a").

```
select 
    objectid,
    a.shape.numpts as num_points,
    a.shape.points as byte_stream
from 
    a_test_fc a
```

[image]

---

That technique also works for SDO_GEOMETRY *methods*:

```
select 
    a.shape.get_wkt()
from 
    table a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle's [TREAT()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TREAT.html#GUID-037C0CD3-C256-4A02-80E0-C6F15147C5BF) function.

```
select 
    objectid,
    treat(shape as sde.st_geometry).numpts as num_points,
    treat(shape as sde.st_geometry).points as byte_stream
from 
    a_test_fc
```

[image]

---

Related:

[How to SELECT from object type column in Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318272/how-to-select-from-object-type-column-in-oracle-11g)

[What is the ST_Geometry storage type?](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm)

[image]